# MYSQL query not equal to not working as supposed to

Tags: mysql

**What I am trying to do:** Multi word search, and when the user selects pub from the drop down it needs to only retrieve records where pub is not equal to '-' in the table.

**What's going wrong:** It does some filtering but the last record is a record with a '-'

**What I have tried:**

I've tried the following query in the MySQL console.

My query:

```
SELECT * FROM ticker where pub <> '-' AND (summary LIKE '%funny%' OR cust_exp LIKE '%funny%') OR (summary LIKE '%joke%' OR cust_exp LIKE '%joke%') OR (summary LIKE '%impact%' OR cust_exp LIKE '%impact%') ORDER BY `created` DESC
```

The above query is generated via:

constructing the multi-word search..

```
$words = explode(" ",$keywords);

        $queryWords = '';
        $i=0;  

        foreach($words as $each){
            $i++;

            if ($i == 1){
                $queryWords.=" (summary LIKE '%$each%' OR cust_exp LIKE '%$each%') ";   
            }
            else{
                $queryWords.=" OR (summary LIKE '%$each%' OR cust_exp LIKE '%$each%') ";    
            }
          }
```

snippet of query code..

```
elseif ($ticket_type == 'Pub'){
                if ($status == 'All'){
                        if (empty($product)){
                            $query="SELECT * FROM ticker where pub <> '-' AND".$queryWords."ORDER BY `$order_by` DESC";
                        }
```

EDIT: Sample search string is 'funny joke impact'

Comment: Are you using `pub = '-'` as an empty indicator? If so, `NULL` might be better for this.

Comment: @halfer: nope, the column has a '-'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM ticker 
WHERE TRIM(pub) != '-' 
  AND (
    (summary LIKE '%funny%' OR cust_exp LIKE '%funny%') 
    OR
    (summary LIKE '%joke%' OR cust_exp LIKE '%joke%')
    OR 
    (summary LIKE '%impact%' OR cust_exp LIKE '%impact%')
  ) 
ORDER BY `created` DESC
```

Comment: Thanks. I see what I needed to do with the `()` after the `AND` to construct a compound statement. Will accept answer when it lets me.

Comment: Aha, good spot. I missed that the brackets didn't extend around the `OR` block! +1.

Answer (score 0):

check your query

> AND".$queryWords."ORDER 
>   you dont have spaces between the "AND" and the "ORDER BY"

Comment: @MateiMihai: BlackHat has a point though. Even if it works, the code looks wrong, and so will take up developer time every time it is looked at. Putting spaces in the code strings to _ensure_ it is correct is, I think, a good idea. +1

Comment: @halfer I never said that this is not a good idea. I'm totally agree with you, but BlackHatShadow said that the problem of getting that wrong result, is that the query is not well formated, which is not correct! This is what I've wanted to say..

Comment: @MateiMihai - my crystal ball here says that's what you meant to say! `</joking>`

Comment: @greenpool - in PHP, you can even split strings over multiple lines, so you can specify a SQL string by starting off with a `"`, copying in the statement from Matei's answer, then finishing with a `"`. You can even indent it, and the database won't mind the extra tabs at all. This approach makes for very readable code, as it negates scrolling off to the right in your editor.

Answer (score 0):

$Where[] = "pub <> '-'";

$words = explode(" ", $keywords);

foreach($words as $ThisWord)$WhereWord[] = "summary LIKE '%{$ThisWord}%' OR cast_exp LIKE '%{$ThisWord}%'";

$Where[] = "(".implode(" OR ", $WhereWord).")";

$queryWords = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ".implode(" AND ", $Where)." ORDER BY '{$order_by}' DESC";

print $queryWords;

Comment: Just so you know, there's a `code` button in the SO editor that will pre-format your code samples.